# ng-packagr: Cannot find namespace Interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shared-libraries, ng-packagr

I try to build a service library. I normaly usethe Interface in the service file. phpStorm didnt create for this a "import" statement and it works fine with `ng serve`

```
public list$: Observable<Platform.PlatformInterface[]>;

private _platform: AngularFirestoreCollection<Platform.PlatformInterface>;

constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this._platform = db.collection<Platform.PlatformInterface>('platforms');
    this.list$ = this._platform.valueChanges();
}
```

Here the Interface: (I reduce it only to the Root of the interface because its clearer then in this post. Normaly there are more interfaces)

```
declare module PlatformInterface {

    export interface Root {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        design: Design[];
        saga: Saga[];
    }

}
```

But when i run `npm run packagr` i got this error:

```
BUILD ERROR
src/app/services/platform.service.ts(12,30): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Platform'.
```

Any Ideas? i tryed allready to import the interface in the public_api.ts but this didnt works for me.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY after so long I've found a solution that works for me.

Use the [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) at the top of your .ts files that use the namespace. For example, my namespace

```
declare module google {
    export module maps {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

is declared in `../../typings.d.ts` (relative to the file referencing it), so I put

```
/// <reference path="../../typings.d.ts" />
```

at the top of the file referencing it, in order to access the google namespace.

This was suggested by the ng-packagr creator in his comment [here](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/193#issuecomment-338009572) in a GitHub issue.

Comment: Only problem now is that newer versions of angular does not include typings.d.ts. I have the same problem but I am using angular 7 and it does not need typings.d.ts